# Storing JQuery string values in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

So I'm webmastering this page full of ebulletins and ppl are asking options to sort different bulletins by their importance. So I created this nice little JQuery thingy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_all").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("show","all");
        $("div#tiedotteet_infonet div").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

So the div element which display value I'm changing is `none` in css and I'm using JQuery to switch it to `block` but I also wan't to store this click into localStorage to key-value-pair "show" and "all", so I can make code to check which is the users preference when she comes back to the page. The button and similarly constructed buttons work fine in the way that they are showing or hiding the div elements (and the bulletins inside them) when the user is clicking different buttons. But the code won't store anything to localStorage according to Chrome. I'm obviously doing something wrong here. What that might be?

Comment: doesn't make sense that it isn't being stored. Easy to determine by  `console.log(localStorage.getItem("show"))`

Comment: not all browsers support `localStorage`, it looks like you are using the api correctly, are there any errors thrown when you call `localStorage.setItem("show", "all");`?

Comment: nearly all browsers support localStorage -- see: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: For some mysterious reason the code started to work after I inserted the statement charlietfl suggested. Before that Chrome's Recources --> Local Storage --> File:// didn't show anything on key/value columns. Now it shows the correct key-value pairs. Thx Charlie. :)

My code is working now on Chrome and Firefox. Buttons are hiding and revealing divs and the browser is remembering the selected choice. How ever, it doesn't work on IE11 which I don't get since it should support localStorage. I think I have to post another question with the whole code pasted.